# MS Access Percentages of Column Values

Tags: ms-access

I have a simple Access table called `Test`, with two columns - `Field1` and `Field2`. The data in the table looks like this.

```
Field1  Field2
1       2
2       2
2       2
2       1
2       1
```

I'm trying to return the percentage of times each data type exists in each column. (ie - In Field1, the number 1 exists 20% and the number 2 exists 80%)

I found this query and it works great returning one column at a time.

```
Select Field1, (Count(Field1)* 100 / (select Count(*) From Test)) as fieldA
FROM Test
Group By Field1;
```

How would I select both columns? I tried this but it doesn't work.

```
Select 
  Field1, (Count(Field1)* 100 / (select Count(*) From Test)) as fieldA,
  Field2, (Count(Field2)* 100 / (select Count(*) From Test)) as fieldB
FROM Test
Group By Field1;
```

Sorry for posting such a simple question. I just started using Access a few days ago.

Thanks,

Anne

Comment: In the future please use only the tag for the version you actually use, or the generic [ms-access] tag if your question isn't specific for any particular version. There is no need to include tags for more versions, in fact it only confuses.

Comment: Sorry about that, I'll make sure to do that in the future. 

What would the code look like if I wanted to add a Field3?

Comment: To add another field, just add another sub query and join it in the same way as the one for field2

Comment: Thanks jpw from Stockholm :)

I tried it a bunch of different ways, thought this would work but I get a  missing operator syntax error. 

select * from (
    SELECT Field1, (Count(Field1)* 100 / (select Count(*) From Test)) as fieldA 
    FROM Test 
    GROUP BY Field1
    ) a 
inner join (
    SELECT Field2, (Count(Field2)* 100 / (select Count(*) From Test)) as fieldB 
    FROM Test 
    GROUP BY Field2
    ) b on a.Field1 = b.Field2
inner join (
    SELECT Field3, (Count(Field3)* 100 / (select Count(*) From Test)) as fieldC 
    FROM Test 
    GROUP BY Field3
    ) c on a.Field1 = c.Field3

Comment: Ok, Access uses a pretty odd syntax when joining multiple tables, I think this should do what you want: `SELECT *
FROM ((SELECT Field1, (Count(Field1) * 100 / (select Count(*) From Test)) as fieldA FROM Test GROUP BY Field1)  AS a INNER JOIN (SELECT Field2, (Count(Field2) * 100 / (select Count(*) From Test)) as fieldB FROM Test GROUP BY Field2)  AS b ON a.Field1 = b.Field2) INNER JOIN (SELECT Field3, (Count(Field3) * 100 / (select Count(*) From Test)) as fieldC FROM Test GROUP BY Field3)  AS c ON a.Field1 = c.Field3;`

Comment: You're the best jpw!! You helped me tremendously, thank you very much!

Comment: It's strange, now when I try to add a 4th field, it complains about the From statement!

LEFT JOIN (
   SELECT Field3, (Count(Field3) * 100 / (select Count(*) From Test)) as fieldC 
   FROM Test 
   GROUP BY Field3) AS c ON a.Field1 = c.Field3)
LEFT JOIN (
   SELECT Field4, (Count(Field4) * 100 / (select Count(*) From Test)) as fieldD 
   FROM Test 
   GROUP BY Field4) AS d ON a.Field1 = d.Field4;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way (of many) to do this is to do two separate queries (one for each field) and wrap them in an outer query like this:

```
select * from (
    SELECT Field1, (Count(Field1)* 100 / (select Count(*) From Test)) as fieldA 
    FROM Test 
    GROUP BY Field1
    ) a 
inner join (
    SELECT Field2, (Count(Field2)* 100 / (select Count(*) From Test)) as fieldB 
    FROM Test 
    GROUP BY Field2
    ) b on a.Field1 = b.Field2
```

This would give the following result:

```
Field1  fieldA  Field2  fieldB
1       20      1       40
2       80      2       60
```

This assumes the same numbers exists in both columns; if it can be that a number only exists in one of the columns you might want to change the `inner join` to a `left join` instead.

Edit: As a follow-up to the modifications asked for in the comments to the question (adding more fields) it's worth mentioning that due to the join semantics in Access-SQL it might be easier to take another approach, and save a query for each of the aggregate statement `SELECT Field1, (Count(Field1)* 100 / (select Count(*) From Test)) AS fieldA FROM Test GROUP BY Field1;` and then use the visual query design tool to build a query that uses the previously saved queries as source.

Comment: You are awesome, thank you so much. I can't rep you because I don't have 15 rep!! Thanks again!

Comment: I think you should be able to accept his answer at your rep though *hint hint* ;)

Comment: @AnneString I've updated my answer with a different approach that might be helpful for you if you want to add more fields.